# Is there any way to retrieve only completed video not live streaming?

Tags: android, youtube-api

HI I am developing an android app. I'm using Youtube API v3.
As I mention on question title, Is there way? because I send command to Youtube server, they return video and live streaming.
I tried to find options to exclude live streaming video but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to retrieve  non-livestreaming videos in Youtube. Use the HTTP request

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`

to perform the operation.

Give the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) a go to see the results in your browser right now.

Since you're using Android, this code snippet from the same page might give you an idea:

```
    // Call the YouTube Data API's youtube.videos.list method to
    // retrieve the resources that represent the specified videos.
    YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, recordingDetails").setId(videoId);
    VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();
    List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();
```